# ¿Cómo obtener un conjunto de resultados de tablas relacionadas?

Tags: base-de-datos, backend

Siempre me he preguntado cual sería la mejor manera de realizar una consulta de una tabla en la cual dependen muchas tablas de ella. Por ejemplo una tabla producto, esta tabla puede tener relacionada las siguientes tablas:

- producto_imagen
- producto_caracteristica
- producto_categoria
- producto_marca
- producto_color
- producto_material, entre otros.

Entonces en base a este problema, ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de realizar una consulta y traer la información completa de un producto en específico?
He preguntado a algunas personas y algunos dicen traerlos todos mediante group by y en el back end crear un método en la cual lo dividas para al final tener la información exacta, pero esto conlleva a tener una cantidad grande de datos al inicio, otros dicen traerlos por diferentes llamadas a la base de datos pero esto conllevaría a realizar múltiples transacciones.

Comment: Entonces mas que buenas prácticas tu duda debería estar enfocada en como construir la consulta para obtener determinados datos, te recomiendo para evitar el cierre de esta publicación leas [ask] y proveas un [mcve]

Comment: Exactamente, la respuesta dependerá de lo que quieras obtener. ¿Podrías plantear un caso más concreto?

Comment: Para relaciones 1:1 basta con `INNER JOIN`, para las otras depende del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Por los nombres de las tablas que mencionas, se deduce que todas son atributos categorizados del producto y de cardinalidad 1:N. Es decir, que en la tabla `productos` almacenas diferentes `id` que se corresponden con cada una de las características detalladas en las tablas y únicamente con ésas. Lo habrás hecho así para restringir el número posible de colores, categorías, materiales, etc.

En el caso de que tengas una tabla `productos` con un montón de características que has reducido a números, no te hace falta conectar las tablas hasta el final. Haz con esos números todos los `GROUP BY` que necesites y ya mostrarás a qué características corresponde cada `id` cuando hayas terminado de hacer todas las operaciones de agrupamiento o totales.

Un `id` ocupa menos espacio en memoria que un color, categoría o material. Si quieres saber cuál es el color más utilizado, no es necesario combinar las tablas antes de hacer el conteo. Haces el conteo con los `id` en la misma tabla `productos` y, cuando lo hayas obtenido, ya haces el `JOIN` únicamente con los que te interesen.